# How to estimate the order of this integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, limits-and-convergence

**Some introduction:**
Given a homogeneous structure called "dilation" in $R^n$: For $t\geq 0$
$$D_t: R^n\rightarrow R^n$$
$$D_t(x)=(t^{a_1}x_1,...,t^{a_n}x_n)$$
where $1=a_1\leq...\leq a_n$, and $a_i$ are all integers. And we call $Q=a_1+...+a_n$ the homogeneous dimension. In our problem, we only consider when $Q>n\geq  2$.

Now consider the integral:
$$J(r)=\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{dx}{P(x,r)}=\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{dx}{f_n(x)r^n+f_{n+1}(x)r^{n+1}+...+f_Q(x)r^Q}$$
where $f_k(x)$ satisfies:

(1) $f_k(D_t(x))=t^{Q-k}f_k(x)$ for all $x\in R^n$ and $t\geq0$

(2) $f_k(x)$ is the combination of some positive monomials. (Examples will be shown below)

(3) $f_Q(x)=Constant>0$. (This property follows from other theorems and propositions, but they are too many so I don't describe them here.)

Four examples are the followings:

(ex1)  In $R^2$, $D_t(x)=(tx_1,t^2x_2)$, so $Q=3$. And Let $P(x,r)=x_1r^2+r^3$.

(ex2) In $R^3$,  $D_t(x)=(tx_1,tx_2,t^2x)$, so $Q=4$. Let $P(x,r)=(x_1+x_2)r^3+r^4$

(ex3) In $R^3$, $D_t(x)=(t^{1}x_1,t^2x_2,t^{3}x_3)$, so $Q=6$. Let $P(x,r)= x_1^3r^3+(x_2+3x_1^2)r^4+5x_1r^5+3r^6$

(ex4)  In $R^3$, $D_t(x)=(t^{1}x_1,t^2x_2,t^{3}x_3)$, so $Q=6$. Let $P(x,r)= x_1x_2r^3+(x_2+2x_1^2)r^4+3x_1r^5+r^6$

(You will find that $x_n$ doesn't make effort. In my work $x_n$ do make no sense in the integral but this  follows from other theorems, and it doesn't matter here.  )

**Problem:** Find the order of $J(r)$ when $r$ goes to $0^+$. Like the following description.

**Attempt and information:** I guess $J(r)=\frac{1}{r^\alpha}I(r)$, where the $\alpha$ is the "critical value", that is:

(i) $\liminf_\limits{r\rightarrow0^+}I(r)>0$.

(ii) for any $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow0^+}r^\epsilon I(r)=0$.

I will give the reason why I guess so in the below. I can show that $g_p(r)=r^p J(r)$, then there exists $p_0$ s.t. when $a<p_0$, $\lim_\limits{r\rightarrow0^+}g_a(r)>0$ and when $a>p_0$, $\lim_\limits{r\rightarrow0^+}g_a(r)=0$. But I can't show $\lim_\limits{r\rightarrow0^+}g_{p_0}(r)>0$, that is, I can't show the (i) above. (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769564/how-to-find-the-critical-index-a-of-xafx) One gave a counterexample for the proposition in that link. But its counterexample *will not* appear in this problem. Because this is a rational fractional integral. The $I(r)$ I guess will be like the combination of $\log$ and $\arctan$.

The four example have the order estimates:

(ex1) We can calculate directly:
$$J(r)=\frac{1}{r^2}\ln(1+\frac{1}{r})=\frac{1}{r^2}I(r)$$
where $ I(r)$ satisfies (i)(ii) above.

(ex2)
$$J(r)=\frac{1}{r^3}I(r)$$
where $I(r)$ can be calculate or one can use Dominate convergence theorem to estimate that $I(r)$ satisfies (i)(ii)

(ex3)
$$J(r)=\frac{1}{r^{3+2/3}}I(r)$$
see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718932/estimate-a-integral-with-parameter

(ex4)
$$J(r)=\frac{1}{r^{3}}I(r)$$
First
$$J(r)=\frac{1}{r^3}\int_{[0,1]^2}\frac{dxdy}{xy+(y+2x^2)r+3xr^2+r^3}=\frac{1}{r^3}I(r)$$
we can show $I(r)$ satisfies (i)(ii):

(i) change variables:
$$I(r)=\int_{0}^{1/r^2}\int_{0}^{1/r}\frac{dxdy}{xy+(y+2x^2)+3x+1}$$
and then obviously.

(ii) for $3>\epsilon>0$ (the part $\epsilon\geq 3$ follows from the part $3>\epsilon>0$),
$$r^\epsilon I(r)=\int_{[0,1]^2}\frac{r^\epsilon}{xy+(y+2x^2)r+3xr^2+r^3}dxdy=\int_{[0,1]^2}h_r(x,y)dxdy=\int_{(0,1)^2}h_r(x,y)dxdy$$
Pointwisely $\lim_\limits{r\rightarrow0^+}h_r(x,y)=0$ in $(0,1)^2$. Now look for a dominating function in $(0,1)^2$:
$$\frac{1}{h_r(x,y)}\geq \frac{xy}{r^\epsilon}+r^{3-\epsilon}\geq C(xy)^{1-\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$$
So $h_r(x,y)\leq \frac{C}{(xy)^{1-\frac{\epsilon}{3}}}$ in $(0,1)^2$, which is integrable. By DCT, we have $I(r)$ satisfying (i)(ii). **But this method doesn't work in other examples like (ex3)**.

Based on the four examples, I guess $$J(r)=\frac{1}{r^\alpha}I(r).$$ But I can't show how to find the critical value $\alpha$ and even it's difficult to show the existence of critical value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you care only about the order of magnitude (i.e., an answer up to a constant factor), in which case it is fairly easy.

First, ignore all coefficients. Setting them to $1$ just changes the answer at most constant number of times. Now, suppose we have the denominator of the form $\sum_{(\alpha,\beta)} x^\alpha r^\beta$ where $\alpha$ is a multi-index with real entries and $\beta$ is a real number. The sum is assumed to be finite. Make the change of variable $x_j=e^{-y_j}$. Now, at each point, only the maximal term matters (up to a factor that is the total number of terms). In terms of $y$'s, the condition of maximality of $x^\alpha r^\beta$ is $y_j\ge 0$,
$$
\langle y,\alpha-\alpha'\rangle\le (\beta'-\beta)\log(1/r)
$$
for all $(\alpha',\beta')\ne(\alpha,\beta)$. This domain is just a fixed polyhedron $P_{\alpha,\beta}$ stretched $\log(1/r)$ times (we keep only those with non-empty interiors in what follows; also I call it a "polyhedron" though, technically, it can be unbounded). Thus,
$$
J(r)\asymp\sum_{(\alpha,\beta)}r^{-\beta}\int_{(log\frac 1r)P_{\alpha,\beta}}e^{\psi_{\alpha,\beta}(y)}\,dy
$$
where $\psi_{\alpha,\beta}(y)=\langle \alpha-e,y\rangle$, $e=(1,\dots,1)$.

Now the life becomes straightforward. All you need is to find the order of magnitude of each integral. I'll drop the indices $\alpha,\beta$ for brevity. Let $F$ be the face of $P$ on which $\psi$ attains its maximum $p$ and let $d$ be the dimension of $F$. If $\psi\equiv 0$ (i.e., $\alpha=e$), we just have $F=P$ and $\int_{(\log\frac 1r)P}e^{\psi}=V(P)\log^d(1/r)$. Consider now the non-trivial situation when $\psi$ is not $0$. Then we can rotate and shrink the coordinate system so that $-\psi(y)$ becomes a new variable $t$. Also we can shift $P$ along this coordinate so that the face $F$ lies on the corresponding coordinate hyperplane $\{t=0\}$. Then the integral in question is just
$$
e^{p\log(1/r)}(\log^{D-1}\frac 1r)\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}S_P(\frac t{\log{1/r}})\,dt
$$
where $S_P(\tau)$ is the $D-1$-dimensional volume of the cross-section of $P$ by the hyperplane $\{t=\tau\}$. By the general convex geometry nonsense, for small $\tau$, $S_P(\tau)=v_d\tau^{D-1-d}+v_{d-1}\tau^{D-d}+\dots+v_0\tau^{D-1}$ where $v_d>0$ and then it becomes smaller (look up "mixed volumes" on Google if you are interested in the details), whence the leading term in the integral becomes $\log^d\frac 1r$ with some coefficient depending on $P$. Thus, the final answer for the integral we are interested in with the factor $r^{-\beta}$ is
$$
\asymp r^{-p_{\alpha,\beta}-\beta}\log^{d_{\alpha,\beta}}\frac 1r
$$
We have several competing terms like that, so the winning one is the one with largest $p+\beta$ and among those the one with the largest $d$.

In your last example $x_1x_2+x_1^2r+x_2r+x_1r^2+r^3$ (I ignore $r^3$ that can be carried out and all the coefficients), we have $5$ polyhedra and functionals (I drop the trivial restrictions $y_1,y_2\ge 0$):
$$
P_{1,1,0}=\{-y_1+y_2\le 1, y_1\le 1, y_2\le 2, y_1+y_2\le 3\},
\\
\psi_{1,1,0}(y)=0 
\\
P_{2,0,1}=\{y_1-y_2\le -1, 2y_1-y_2\le 0, y_1\le 1,2y_1\le 2\}, 
\\
\psi_{2,0,1}(y)=y_1-y_2
\\
et\ cetera.
$$
Here $P_{1,1,0}$ dominates and yields $\log^2\frac 1r$ but it may be instructive to find the contribution of $P_{2,0,1}$. In this case (just draw the picture) $p=-1$, $\beta=1$, $d=1$, so we get $\log\frac 1r$.

Comment: Sorry I am difficult to understand some point could you give more details? (1) From "$x_j=e^{-y_j}$" to "where $\psi_{\alpha,\beta}(y)=<\alpha-e,y>$" . I am confused. For example (ex1) $\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{r+x}$ (ignore $r^2$ that can be carried out). After $x=e^{-y}$, we have $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{e^yr+1}$.  By your fomula, It $\asymp \int_{\log(1/r)P_{0,1}}e^{-y}dy+\int_{\log(1/r)P_{1,0}}1dy$, so in this case what are $P_{0,1}$ and $P_{1,0}$? can they be written down? (question (2) in next comment)

Comment: And question (2): In your answer, for the last example (ex4), your answer show that the $I(r)\asymp r\log(\frac{1}{r})$, that is $J(r)\asymp\frac{1}{r^2}I(r)$. But in my description, (ex4) is $J(r)\asymp\frac{1}{r^3}I(r)$. Is there anything wrong in my description or something else?

Comment: @Houa Oops, I forgot about $r^\beta$ in my final answer. I edited. So the contribution of $P_2$ is actually $\log(1/r)$. However, it is still $P_1$ that dominates (contributing $\log^2(1/r)$, so $J(r)\asymp r^{-3}\log^2(1/r)$ in full agreement with what you wrote). As to question 1, by my (corrected) formula the integral is $\asymp r^{-1}\int_{\log(1/r)P_{0,1}}e^{-y}dy+\int_{\log(1/r)P_{1,0}}1dy$. From the definition with linear inequalities (just drop $\log(1/r)$ on the RHS), $P_{1,0}=\{0\le y\le 1\}=[0,1]$ and $P_{0,1}=\{y>0,-y\le-1\}=[1,+\infty]$ so you get your $\log(1/r)+1\asymp\log(1/r)$

Comment: @Houa Is it clearer now? If not, what should I clarify? (I addressed two explicit questions you asked but I suspect more clarification may be still needed, so don't hesitate to ask for it but try to explain what exactly you are confused about)

Comment: I've understood how to calculate $P_{\alpha,\beta}$ and use this method to calculate some examples. The answer is right. Your idea is wonderful! Now I want to know some details. Question (3): there will be some $P_{\alpha,\beta}$ with its n-dimension Lebesgue 
measure zero. In this case, we can ignore that term, right? Because its integral is zero.  Question (4): It seems that you didn't show the existence of maximum of $\psi_{\alpha,\beta}(y)$. It seems not obvious, for $P_{\alpha,\beta}$ may be unbounded.

Comment: Question (5): the changing of variables makes me confused. Do you rotate $P$ first then let $-\psi(y)=t$? For example , if $P=\{1<y_1<2, 1<y_2<3\}$ and $\psi$ attains the max in line $l=\{y_2=3,1<y_1<2\}$. Then we first rotate the rectangle and shift it s.t. $l$ lies in $y_1=0$? Then let $-\psi(y)=t$? In fact I don't know how you get the integral after changing the variable. Is there any formula?  Question (6) : Is the expansion of $S_p$ one type of " Steiner formula" ?  (In fact if I understand question (5) then I think I can almost understand the whole answer.)

Comment: (3) Yes, of course. As I said "ignore everything with empty interior". (4) It follows from the physical meaning of your particular problem: since you have a constant term, the integral should converge, and if $\psi$ is unbounded (or the face $F$ on which the maximum is attained is unbounded), you'll certainly just get $+\infty$ immediately. This *can* happen in the general setting I considered but your particular case is tame. (5) Yes, you can think of it as first rotating the rectangle and then shifting it or you can think of first shifting the origin and then rotating the coordinate frame.

Comment: @Houa (6) Yes, it is related to it (read the previous comment for (3-5); I forgot to address it to you). As to the integral, just integrate term by term. The claim is that if $f(t)$ is any function that equals $p(t)=\sum_k c_kt^k$ ($c_k>0$) near the origin and is always between $0$ and $p(t)$, then $\int_0^\infty f(\delta t)e^{-t}\,dt\approx \sum_k k!c_k\delta^k$ as $\delta\to 0$.

Comment: Thinks for answering patiently! To (5) yesterday, I try to do the changing of variable, could you point out something wrong for me? (For brevity let $b=\log(1/r)$). First $\int_{bP}e^{\psi(y)}dy=b^n\int_{P}e^{b\psi(y)}dy$, then let $-\psi(y)=t$, we have $b^n\int_{A(P)} e^{-bt} |det(A)|dtdt_2...dt_n=b^n|det(A)|\int_{-p}^\infty e^{-bt}S_P(t)dt$, where $A$ is a transform matrix (then |det(A)| will be ignored,) and since $-t\leq p$ now. Then let $t'=t+p$, we have $e^{bp}b^n\int_{0}^\infty e^{-bt'}S_P(t'-p)dt$. Lastly, let $bt'=u$ we have $e^{bp}b^{n-1}\int_{0}^\infty S_P(\frac{u}{b}-p)du$.

Comment: (going on with the last comment)  in your answer is $S_P(t/b)$ but in my comment is $S_P(u/b-p)$, where $b=\log(1/r)$ and $p$ is the maximum. And others almost the same...(In last comment some typo mistake I can't edit……  The last integral is $e^{bp}b^{n-1}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-u}S_P(u/b-p)du$)

Comment: @Houa That's all right, but note that I also first *shifted the origin to the point where the maximum is attained* (so I should rather say "*making $t=p-\psi(y)$ a new coordinate*" if I had used the original $y$, not $y$ with respect to the shifted origin), in which case the shift in the argument of $S_P$ disappears and our formulae agree. I apologize for being somewhat confusing here

Comment: In fact neither $S_P(t/b)$ nor $S_P(t/b-p)$ changes the order of  $J(r)$, so it doesn't matter :-).  And some extra questions. (7) if, say $J(r)=\int_{(-1,1)^3}\frac{dxdydz}{|x-y|+|x^2-z|r+r^2}$, do you think the method you did in the answer still works here? Or we should find some new ways? (8) would you mind give your real name and institution to us? Since your idea helps us a lot with a lemma in our research, and we want to write an acknowledgement in paper (if we write this lemma in it). My email is in my userpage profile page

Comment: (7)(8) may be the last two questions and Thank you very much these days

Comment: @Houa (7). Your new $J(r)$ is more tricky. Part of what I said still applies, but now the maximality condition of each individual term is different because you can no longer say that there is no cancellation between the terms though *most of the time* it is still so, but you now encounter extra fancy regions where the largest terms may cancel. If you want to pursue this venue, just post a new question: this comment thread is already too long. (8) Just credit MO. They have guidelines for how to do it somewhere.